# How to rectify this error in c#?

Tags: c#

The program is fine but there is a small error. Before I have posted the same program with different error, but now its showing new error.

```
using System;
class Methodcalling
{
    public void Values(int num1, int num2)
    {

        if (num1 > num2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("num2 is large ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("num1 is big");
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a, b;
        Methodcalling m = new Methodcalling();


        Console.WriteLine("enter a no.:");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("enter a no.:");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int result = m.Values(a, b);

    }
}
```

> ERROR: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int'

Comment: because you method Values() return type is void, and it wont return anything. But you are trying to get return value and set it to int variable

Comment: Well yes - your method has a return type of `void`, but you're trying to assign the result to an `int` value. What do you expect that to do? What do you expect `Values` to return? Do you actually need it to return a value at all? You could just call the method without doing anything with the non-existent return value - it's not like you're using `result` afterwards.

Comment: See the return type of your `Values`method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `Values()` has been declared as `void` - the method that doesn't return anything.

Doing this:

```
int result = m.Values(a, b);
```

you expect that method returns `int` value.

So, you should change your code in `Main`(simply call your method):

```
m.Values(a, b); // without int result =
```

**OR**

Change your method to:

```
public int Values(int num1, int num2) // int instead of void
```

and add `return` statement to return some value from that method:

```
return 0; // your value instead of 0
```

In this situation it will be better not to change the method (first case in this answer), because you don't do any calculations and simply print to `Console`. So, there is nothing to return.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign nothing (`void`) to an int:

```
int result = m.Values(a, b);
```

You have two options:

change `public void Values(int num1, int num2)` to `public int Values(int num1, int num2)` and return something useful if applicable;

Or

Do not assign result, just call `m.Values(a, b);`

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
int result = m.Values(a, b);
```

you call method `Values` which returns no value (`void`)

```
public void Values(int num1, int num2)
```

You can just call method like this:

```
m.Values(a, b);
```

Or redesign `Values` method to return some value.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to receive a value from your `m.Values` method. But you declared the return value as `void`, which means you don't want your method to return a value.

Change your declaration from `void` to `int` and return an int value depending on the if case

Answer (score 0):

Every method returns a value(execpt a void methods) that is declared in the signature of your method.

For example:

```
public int Values(int num1, int num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

return int type,

```
public float Values(int num1, int num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

return float type.

And then we have `void` method that return nothing. `Void` can do many things but always have no return value.

in `int result = m.Values(a, b);`
you trying to force your void method to return int